# What is stat_density calculating in stacked density charts?

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot, stacked-area-chart

As an example, here a stacked density chart based on `diamonds`. A simple table suggests that "Fair" cut should be quite uncommon, and "Ideal" the most common, etc..., but the five cuts seem to occupy a more or less equal area/ proportion on the stacked charts. That is surprising to me.

This is probably a conceptual misunderstanding from my side and I'd be grateful for someone to help. So, what does stacked density exactly show?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- diamonds %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = price, fill = cut), position = "stack")

p2 <- diamonds %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = price, fill = cut), position = "fill")

p1 / p2 + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

```r
table(diamonds$cut)
#> 
#>      Fair      Good Very Good   Premium     Ideal 
#>      1610      4906     12082     13791     21551
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The area under a kernel density always sums to 1, and each cut's density is calculated separately, then stacked. It therefore doesn't matter how many points are in each `cut`, they will all be about the same height. If you look at the help file, you'll see that `after_stat(count)` is the density * number of points, _"which is useful for stacked density plots."_ , because it simply multiplies the density function in each group by the number of points in that group to show the proportional weight of each group.

Comment: thanks Allan. I have had a look at the help file but have missed this sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The densities are being normalized (i.e. scaled to area 1) before being combined.  If you don't want that, use `after_stat(count)`, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = price, y = after_stat(count), 
                   fill = cut), 
               position = "stack")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Edited to add:

Here's how this works: `geom_density()` always computes the normalized density for each group.  Setting `y = after_stat(count)` tells it to multiply the density by the count for the group, so you get "number of cases per unit of `price`" instead of "probability per unit of `price`", the usual units of the density.

If you'd like to keep the density scale, you can use

```
diamonds %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = price, 
                   y = after_stat(count/sum(tapply(n, group, unique))), 
                   fill = cut), 
               position = "stack") +
  ylab("Density")
```

This will actually show "subdensities", where the total area is 1, and the area of each region is the proportion of cases of that class.  (The expression `sum(tapply(n, group, unique))` is a fancy way to compute `nrow(diamonds)` without referring to the particular dataset.  It says:  find the unique values of `n` in each group, and add them up.  Since `n` is the same for all entries in the group, that gives the overall total.  Thanks to @Stefan for the trick.)

Comment: Thanks. The plot makes more sense to me now. What would "normalised" mean in this case? Normalised against what?

Comment: Normalized so the area under the density is equal to 1.

Comment: This answer is correct (+1), but I don't think the explanation is quite right. Density is _always_ normalized to 1. `after_stat(count)` doesn't _avoid_ normalization, rather it multiplies the density by the number of points in the group, so that the area under each curve is equal to the number of points in each group, allowing a proportional comparison.

Comment: @AllanCameron:  I think that explanation is compatible with my answer.  What change would you suggest?

Comment: I'd probably say something like "The densities for each group are calculated using `stats::density`, which, since they are effectively a p.d.f., always have an area of 1, regardless of the size of the group. If you want a stacked density plot that reflects the relative size of the group, you can use `after_stat(count)`, which multiplies the density by the group size. This is mentioned in the help file, which specifically says `after_stat(count)` is useful for stacked density plots." But it's up to you - your answer is correct either way.

Comment: I think "combined. If you don't want", conspires upon a reader's interpretation to suggest normalization isn't conduced in presence of `after_stat(count)`, even if, on reflection after_stat says,  indeed, normalization necessarily happens(ed). Perhaps "combined. To further emphasize proportionality of groups, use `after_stat(count)` .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I've added an extended explanation.