# Use overall count in formula for aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77469253/2554330) I described how to rescale subgroup densities so that the sum of them had area 1. The code in the solution was:

```r
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = price, y = after_stat(count)/nrow(diamonds), fill = cut), position = "stack") +
  ylab("Density")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This works, but it's not entirely satisfactory to me:  including `nrow(diamonds)` in the `aes()` call means that the formula would need editing if I wanted to use it on a different dataset.

I'd rather include something in the aesthetic calculation that means "the total count for the whole dataset, ignoring the subgroups".

Is there some built-in function or variable that gives that value?

Comment: Does the fifth example from https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html#ref-examples work : `y = after_stat(count / sum(n[!duplicated(group)]))`

Comment: Yes, that does work.  I guess it's effectively the same as @stefan's first solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a look at the underlying data via `layer_data()` a  column named `n` is added to the data which contains the number of observations per group and which could be used in `after_stat` to get number of rows of the original dataset:

And thanks to @Axeman: This also listed in the docs (`?stat_density`) as one of the computed variables:

> after_stat(n) = number of points.

```r
library(ggplot2)

diamonds |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(
    aes(
      x = price, y = after_stat(
        count / sum(tapply(n, group, unique))
      ),
      fill = cut
    ),
    position = "stack"
  )
```

[image]

A second option to pass the dataframe without explicitly naming the dataframe would be to use the `magrittr` pipe, which allows to do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

diamonds %>%
  {
    ggplot(.) +
      geom_density(
        aes(
          x = price, y = after_stat(
            count
          )  / nrow(.),
          fill = cut
        ),
        position = "stack"
      )  
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Also listed in `?stat_density`.

Comment: Haha. Thanks @Axeman. Have overlooked that.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping there was some `tidyverse` magic available, but apparently not (other than `layer_data()`, which I didn't know about).

Comment: I just have made an edit to show a second option which indeed uses some "tidyverse" magic. (: The other approach of course does not rely on `layer_data()`. But `layer_data()` is great to have a look at the underlying data used for plotting and in some cases (e.g. complicated computations) is a quick way to retrieve the data to use it in other plots.

Comment: @stefan.  Thanks!  I like your first solution better, though -- the need for the `{}` around the `ggplot` expression is irritating, and doing it with the base pipe is even harder.